# Custom Sensor type for New Ortho Mapping Workspace in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, raster, arcgis-pro, imagery, satellite

Is it possible to bring a sensor type (Satellite) which is not yet included in the available sensor list to create a new Ortho Mapping Workspace in ArcGIS Pro using Python ?? for example the sensor type for KhalifaSAT is not yet included in the list.

[image]